# iPhone SDK image property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image

I've got a view with an image dynamically loaded. When you click on the image, I want it to load another view with the same image. I've got most of it working, but I'm hung up on getting the image name from the "mother" view.

In this case the "parent" view is avbitView with an UIImage called avbitImage and the child spawned when you click is avbitZoomView which also has an `avbitImage`.

This piece of code works:

```
self.avbitZoomView.title = self.title;
```

whereas, this does not.

```
self.avbitZoomView.avbitImage.image = self.avbitImage.image;
```

This *looks* like it should work, but I'm stuck.??

Comment: Is "avbitImage" an UIImage or an UIImageView?  UIImage doesn't have an "image" property.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need the .image property. avbitImage *is* your UIImage, so `self.avbitZoomView.avbitImage = self.avbitImage;` will work.
note you may want to make a `copy` depending on your memory allocation.

Comment: Alex_c - yes, it is a UIImage (avbitImage). Jessie, I tried your fix and it just generates a blank image. I mean, it's doing something - because it's overwriting the placeholder image I put there in the IB layout, but it isn't picking up the self.avbitImage, that's apparently blank. Thanks all - any more ideas?